# Can I create a android custom control using the xml attributes alone?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, custom-controls, android

Is it possible to create a android UI custom control. I need three labels to be placed inside a single Linear Layout. Should I need to extend Linear Layout class for this purpose?
Is it possible without extending the class(Linear layout) - means using a single xml file with a Linear Layout and the required labels alone? Is it possible to use this xml file alone without extending Linear Layout class??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to create XML layout, just like in Zaz Gmy's answer and create your cusom view by extending LinearLayout. Then you must inflate this layout in your views code with view as parent container:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, true);
```